# How can I improve the question to get it re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Referring to this question (now deleted): *[C# how to inherit from multiple base classes without interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145843/c-sharp-how-to-inherit-from-multiple-base-classes-without-interfaces)*

I wrote the question today. It got almost immediately downvoted and closed because it "needs to be more focused".

I looked at the Stack Overflow guide on [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) for guidance on how I could improve my question and get it re-opened.

All it said was:

[image]

I actually do think I only asked a single question in the post and I'm not sure how I could reduce it or break it up into a set of smaller questions (but please help me do so, so I can re-open it and perhaps others so I can find a solution).

Most of the question content is the setup so that the reader can understand the problem once it is presented plainly. After the setup, I state the ***single*** question clearly:

> The problem is that these objects need both FacConfig2 and FacConfig3 members (see tables above), but when instantiating objects of these classes, they will not contain FacConfig2 config members because they inherit from Conf3Facility which itself inherits directly from the parent class of the Conf2Facility class where the relevant member is introduced. This means that the necessary class to inject the necessary member is skipped in the inheritance chain.

...

> Is there any way to accomplish what I want without code duplication and without using composition in C#?

I also think I state the overall goal of the exercise clearly:

> The goal is to accomplish this with as little code duplication as possible. Most of this can be accomplished with the following hierarchy that allows each relevant property to be defined in only one place

Where "this" references the tables of constraints that appeared *directly above* the goal statement.

Comment: 2 points for what it's worth: first, your first paragraph reveals that you think this might be a discussion question (you're right, by the way). The sheer volume of the question indicates that you're trying to have a one-shot brainstorm over the architecture of your model. Second, if the architecture is being such a problem so soon, you don't yet have a good enough grasp of the problem. None of that fits well with a Q&A format.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thank you for your comment. You are not the first person to assume that this problem has occurred "early" in the development process. On the contrary, this project is over a year in the making. This problem is a minor optimization in code readability for data type hierarchy. I'm wondering if something I said in the question makes people think this project is early in development and if you think there is a better way I could communicate the actuality of the situation.

Comment: Even your tl;dr says you aren't sure what the question "boils down" to and then asks whether two different things are possible, neither of which appears to match the the title. "You are not the first person to assume that this problem has occurred "early" in the development process." I don't think any such assumption is in play here. However, it *is* clear that you are trying to do a bunch of design work all at once, and figure out how to relate multiple classes to each other. That is not a proper fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: First step would be to undelete it, deleted questions, are still considered to determine if you are question banned or not. Did you provide code, that cleared recreated, your programming question? Obviously, deleted questions, cannot be reopened

Comment: *"I looked at the Stack Overflow guide on closed questions for guidance"* - and you got a couple of sentences of information and left you with more questions than answers, the help center is like that. Searching meta is pretty much a must too. For what it's worth, "needs more focus" used to be called "too broad" and that implied the question essentially would need the book to be thrown at you to answer. The better solution would be to read the book yourself instead. The replacement flag is still essentially used like that, regardless of its description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, delete the text at the top of the question,

> "PLEASE do not just read the headline question. This question is nuanced and coming up with a one-liner title is very difficult. If you have a suggestion for a better title, please let me know before downvoting...."

It is will only bring more downvotes and only hinder you in your desire to have the question reopened and answered. Meta information belongs here on the meta site, not in your question.

OK, a moderator has since fixed this, but again for future reference, best to keep meta issues out of a question (or answer).

You've also listed many potential duplicate Q&As that you have reviewed, but what use is that list to anyone trying to answer the question? If I were in your shoes, *after* presenting the full question, I'd consider linking to one or two canonical duplicates and then explain *in fair detail* why their answers do not answer your own question.

Next, your question is *very* long and involved, and this suggests that yes, focus is quite likely an issue, that perhaps you're here too early in your debugging process for this site to be able to accept and answer the question. A question shouldn't require a "TL;DR" section but optimally should be succinct, clear and answerable.

Next, you have some excellent and quite helpful comments that have not been fully addressed by you it seems. The comments suggest to me that the question may in fact be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) type question.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response :)
I have modified the question to take your 2nd point into account. And a mod edited it to take the first point into account.

Comment: As for your 3rd point... I'm not sure the length of a question is necessarily a cause of unfocused-ness. Length probably does correlate inversely with the amount of focus, but I think there may be outlier questions that are simply complex and require significant background information to understand what the problem actually is. Did you have a chance to read the entire question? If so, do you believe there is a way to shorten it while keeping the problem statement easy to understand?

Comment: @JacksonPfeffer: you can choose to not accept my third point, but still, if you want to have the question re-opened and answered, then I have to say that you may be ignoring it at your own peril. If a question is easier to understand and answer, it stands a greater chance of being answered.  And no, I have not read the entire question, as I had question fatigue 1/3 of the way through it. Also, I am not a C# expert.

Comment: But my opinion is just that, my opinion. Let's see what other suggestions that other meta users give.

Comment: You may very well be right about point #3. I wasn't trying to say otherwise I'm sorry. I was just opining. Thank you for your time, effort, and help

Comment: @JacksonPfeffer: You're welcome, and I do wish you success in resolving your problem and getting your question re-opened. One more thing for you to be aware of is the "meta effect" as described in this link, [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/). Note that I have not voted on your main site question, but bringing it to meta will increase its visibility greatly and can result in it receiving more votes than typical. Sometimes the effect is positive, but more often than not, it is negative.

Comment: I just saw your last point point about the XY Problem. I'm not sure that is the problem, but I think I'm going to try to re-write the question with that in mind nonetheless.

Comment: Deleted the question, I'll try to rewrite it and try again